# Copying certain attributes from xml file to another with Python

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to make a script that copies certain attributes of `input.xml` to `output.xml`

input.xml:

```
<i3d>
  <Scene>
    <TransformGroup>
      <TransformGroup name="birch_stage2" translation="50.9362 113.806 -465.889" rotation="180 1.4175 180" scale="1.5 1.5 1.5" clipDistance="599" nodeId="13499" lodDistance="0 120">
        <Shape shapeId="1" name="LOD0" translation="2.27374e-15 0 0" static="true" collisionMask="16789538" angularDamping="0.15" rollingFriction="0.27" density="0.65" clipDistance="500" nodeId="13500" materialIds="611" castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true" splitType="4" splitUvs="0 0 1 0.064 1.65">
          <Shape shapeId="2" name="LOD0attachments" clipDistance="500" nodeId="13501" materialIds="801" castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true"/>
        </Shape>
        <Shape shapeId="3" name="LOD1" clipDistance="1500" nodeId="13502" materialIds="103" castsShadows="true"/>
      </TransformGroup>
      <TransformGroup name="birch_stage4" translation="96.7489 119.845 -469.445" scale="0.3 0.3 0.3" clipDistance="2000" nodeId="13519" lodDistance="0 165">
        <Shape shapeId="10" name="LOD0" static="true" collisionMask="16789538" angularDamping="0.15" rollingFriction="0.27" density="0.65" clipDistance="500" nodeId="13520" materialIds="611" castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true" splitType="4" splitUvs="0 0 1 0.064 1.65">
          <Shape shapeId="11" name="LOD0attachments" clipDistance="500" nodeId="13521" materialIds="801" castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true"/>
        </Shape>
        <Shape shapeId="12" name="LOD1" clipDistance="1500" nodeId="13522" materialIds="90" castsShadows="true"/>
      </TransformGroup>
      <TransformGroup name="birch_stage2" translation="134.159 123.536 -472.109" rotation="180 -72.8097 180" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5" clipDistance="599" nodeId="13523" lodDistance="0 120">
        <Shape shapeId="1" name="LOD0" translation="2.27374e-15 0 0" static="true" collisionMask="16789538" angularDamping="0.15" rollingFriction="0.27" density="0.65" clipDistance="500" nodeId="13524" materialIds="611" castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true" splitType="4" splitUvs="0 0 1 0.064 1.65">
          <Shape shapeId="2" name="LOD0attachments" clipDistance="500" nodeId="13525" materialIds="801" castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true"/>
        </Shape>
        <Shape shapeId="3" name="LOD1" clipDistance="1500" nodeId="13526" materialIds="103" castsShadows="true"/>
      </TransformGroup>
    </TransformGroup>
  </Scene>
</i3d>
```

output.xml:

```
<i3d>
  <Scene>
    <TransformGroup>
      <TransformGroup name="birch_stage2" translation="00.00 00.00 00.00" rotation="0 0 0" scale="0 0 0" clipDistance="599" nodeId="00000" lodDistance="0 120">
        <Shape shapeId="1" name="LOD0" translation="2.27374e-15 0 0" static="true" collisionMask="16789538" angularDamping="0.15" rollingFriction="0.27" density="0.65" clipDistance="500" nodeId="00000" materialIds="611" castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true" splitType="4" splitUvs="0 0 1 0.064 1.65">
          <Shape shapeId="2" name="LOD0attachments" clipDistance="500" nodeId="00000" materialIds="801" castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true"/>
        </Shape>
        <Shape shapeId="3" name="LOD1" clipDistance="1500" nodeId="00000" materialIds="103" castsShadows="true"/>
      </TransformGroup>
      <TransformGroup name="birch_stage4" translation="00.00 00.00 00.00" scale="0 0 0" clipDistance="2000" nodeId="00000" lodDistance="0 165">
        <Shape shapeId="10" name="LOD0" static="true" collisionMask="16789538" angularDamping="0.15" rollingFriction="0.27" density="0.65" clipDistance="500" nodeId="00000" materialIds="611" castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true" splitType="4" splitUvs="0 0 1 0.064 1.65">
          <Shape shapeId="11" name="LOD0attachments" clipDistance="500" nodeId="00000" materialIds="801" castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true"/>
        </Shape>
        <Shape shapeId="12" name="LOD1" clipDistance="1500" nodeId="00000" materialIds="90" castsShadows="true"/>
      </TransformGroup>
      <TransformGroup name="birch_stage2" translation="00.00 00.00 00.00" rotation="0 00.00 0" scale="0 0 0" clipDistance="599" nodeId="00000" lodDistance="0 120">
        <Shape shapeId="1" name="LOD0" translation="2.27374e-15 0 0" static="true" collisionMask="16789538" angularDamping="0.15" rollingFriction="0.27" density="0.65" clipDistance="500" nodeId="00000" materialIds="611" castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true" splitType="4" splitUvs="0 0 1 0.064 1.65">
          <Shape shapeId="2" name="LOD0attachments" clipDistance="500" nodeId="00000" materialIds="801" castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true"/>
        </Shape>
        <Shape shapeId="3" name="LOD1" clipDistance="1500" nodeId="00000" materialIds="103" castsShadows="true"/>
      </TransformGroup>
    </TransformGroup>
  </Scene>
</i3d>
```

I need to copy attributes `translation` `rotation` `scale` and `nodeId` from `TransformGroup` elements that include attribute `name="birch_stage2"` and paste those to `output.xml` to update these attributes. From `Shapes` under the TransformGroup I only need `nodeId`. (Currently all mentioned attributes are bunch of zeros, need to update from `input.xml` to `output.xml`)

I can get a script to print those attributes but update doesn't show in `output.xml`. This is what I made:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

tree2 = ET.parse('output.xml')
root2 = tree2.getroot()

for s3birch in root.findall("./Scene/TransformGroup/TransformGroup[@name='birch_stage2']"):
    translation = s3birch.get('translation')
    rotation = s3birch.get('rotation')
    scale = s3birch.get('scale')
    nodeid = s3birch.get('nodeId')
    print('Translation = ', translation)
    print('rotation = ', rotation)
    print('Scale = ', scale)
    print('NodeId = ', nodeid)
    for shape in root.findall("./Scene/TransformGroup/TransformGroup[@name='birch_stage2']/Shape[@shapeId='1']"):
        shape_nodeid1 = shape.get('nodeId')
        print('Shape 1 nodeId = ', shape_nodeid1)
    for shape2 in root.findall("./Scene/TransformGroup/TransformGroup[@name='birch_stage2']/Shape/Shape[@shapeId='2']"):
        shape_nodeid2 = shape2.get('nodeId')
        print('Shape 2 nodeId = ', shape_nodeid2)
    for shape3 in root.findall("./Scene/TransformGroup/TransformGroup[@name='birch_stage2']/Shape[@shapeId='3']"):
        shape_nodeid3 = shape3.get('nodeId')
        print('Shape 3 nodeId = ', shape_nodeid3)

for new_s3birch in root2.findall("./Scene/TransformGroup/TransformGroup[@name='birch_stage2']"):
    old_translation = new_s3birch.get('translation')
    print(*Old translation = ', old_translation)
    new_s3birch.set('translation', translation)
```

So how do I make it write those attributes to `output.xml`?

I hope you got all of those attributes.

Comment: Jugi. Please clarify. Do you want to filter TransformGroup elements that their name attribute has a specific value, take subset of the attributes (scale,nodeId,etc) and create another xml based on this data? Can you please add a valid XML input. The current one is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working code based on a simplified version of your XML. The code finds the TransformGroup[s] with the requested name attribute and create new simplified TransformGroup elements based on the requested attributes. It dumps the new xml to console and to a file as well.

```
<i3d>
<Scene>
    <TransformGroup name="birch_stage2" translation="50.9362 113.806 -465.889" rotation="180 1.4175 180"
                    scale="1.5 1.5 1.5" clipDistance="599" nodeId="13499" lodDistance="0 120">
        <Shape shapeId="10" name="LOD0" translation="2.27374e-15 0 0" static="true" collisionMask="16789538"
               angularDamping="0.15" rollingFriction="0.27" density="0.65" clipDistance="500" nodeId="13500"
               materialIds="611" castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true" splitType="4"
               splitUvs="0 0 1 0.064 1.65">
            <Shape shapeId="11" name="LOD0attachments" clipDistance="500" nodeId="13501" materialIds="801"
                   castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true"/>
        </Shape>
        <Shape shapeId="12" name="LOD1" clipDistance="1500" nodeId="13502" materialIds="103" castsShadows="true"/>
    </TransformGroup>
    <TransformGroup name="birch_stage4" translation="96.7489 119.845 -469.445" scale="0.3 0.3 0.3"
                    clipDistance="2000" nodeId="13519" lodDistance="0 165">
        <Shape shapeId="1" name="LOD0" static="true" collisionMask="16789538" angularDamping="0.15"
               rollingFriction="0.27" density="0.65" clipDistance="500" nodeId="13520" materialIds="611"
               castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true" splitType="4" splitUvs="0 0 1 0.064 1.65">
            <Shape shapeId="2" name="LOD0attachments" clipDistance="500" nodeId="13521" materialIds="801"
                   castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true"/>
        </Shape>
        <Shape shapeId="3" name="LOD1" clipDistance="1500" nodeId="13522" materialIds="90" castsShadows="true"/>
    </TransformGroup>
    <TransformGroup name="birch_stage2" translation="134.159 123.536 -472.109" rotation="180 -72.8097 180"
                    scale="0.5 0.5 0.5" clipDistance="599" nodeId="13523" lodDistance="0 120">
        <Shape shapeId="10" name="LOD0" translation="2.27374e-15 0 0" static="true" collisionMask="16789538"
               angularDamping="0.15" rollingFriction="0.27" density="0.65" clipDistance="500" nodeId="13524"
               materialIds="611" castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true" splitType="4"
               splitUvs="0 0 1 0.064 1.65">
            <Shape shapeId="11" name="LOD0attachments" clipDistance="500" nodeId="13525" materialIds="801"
                   castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true"/>
        </Shape>
        <Shape shapeId="12" name="LOD1" clipDistance="1500" nodeId="13526" materialIds="103" castsShadows="true"/>
    </TransformGroup>

    <TransformGroup name="not_birch_stage2" translation="134.159 123.536 -472.109" rotation="180 -72.8097 180"
                    scale="0.5 0.5 0.5" clipDistance="599" nodeId="13523" lodDistance="0 120">
        <Shape shapeId="10" name="LOD0" translation="2.27374e-15 0 0" static="true" collisionMask="16789538"
               angularDamping="0.15" rollingFriction="0.27" density="0.65" clipDistance="500" nodeId="13524"
               materialIds="611" castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true" splitType="4"
               splitUvs="0 0 1 0.064 1.65">
            <Shape shapeId="11" name="LOD0attachments" clipDistance="500" nodeId="13525" materialIds="801"
                   castsShadows="true" receiveShadows="true"/>
        </Shape>
        <Shape shapeId="12" name="LOD1" clipDistance="1500" nodeId="13526" materialIds="103" castsShadows="true"/>
    </TransformGroup>
</Scene>
```

Code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement
from xml.dom import minidom


def prettify(elem):
    """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
    """
    rough_string = ET.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ")


id3 = Element('i3d')
scene = SubElement(id3, 'Scene')

tree = ET.parse('input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for s3birch in root.findall("./Scene/TransformGroup[@name='birch_stage2']"):
    transform_group = SubElement(scene, 'TransformGroup')
    for attr in ['translation', 'rotation', 'scale', 'nodeId']:
        transform_group.set(attr, s3birch.get(attr))

print(prettify(id3))
tree = ET.ElementTree(id3)
tree.write("output.xml")
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <i3d>
        <Scene>
            <TransformGroup nodeId="13499" rotation="180 1.4175 180" scale="1.5 1.5 1.5" translation="50.9362 113.806 -465.889"/>
            <TransformGroup nodeId="13523" rotation="180 -72.8097 180" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5" translation="134.159 123.536 -472.109"/>
    </Scene>
   </i3d>
```

Comment: This created xml like this `<i3d><Scene /></i3d>` so didn't work.

Comment: Jugi. The code above shows how to transform xml document to another xml document. The output is shown above. Did you run the code? Did you get the output I have pasted in the answer? What is the expected output (based on the xml I have added as input.xml)

Comment: I did run that code, just noticed that you didn't have the other `<TransformGroup>` element (TranformGroups inside 1 TransformGroup). I need to modify  and update existing `output.xml` which has same structure, but different values for same attfibutes, not a totally new file.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I use lists to store the values and write them to output file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

tree2 = ET.parse('output.xml')
root2 = tree2.getroot()

translations = []
rotations = []
scales = []
nodeids = []
shape_nodes1 = []
shape_nodes2 = []
shape_nodes3 = []

x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
a = 0

for s3birch in root.findall("./Scene/TransformGroup/TransformGroup[@name='birch_stage2']"):
    translation = s3birch.get('translation')
    translations.append(translation)
    rotation = s3birch.get('rotation')
    rotations.append(rotation)
    scale = s3birch.get('scale')
    scales.append(scale)
    nodeid = s3birch.get('nodeId')
    nodeids.append(nodeid)
for shape in root.findall("./Scene/TransformGroup/TransformGroup[@name='birch_stage2']/Shape[@shapeId='1']"):
    shape_nodeid1 = shape.get('nodeId')
    shape_nodes1.append(shape_nodeid1)
for shape2 in root.findall("./Scene/TransformGroup/TransformGroup[@name='birch_stage2']/Shape/Shape[@shapeId='2']"):
    shape_nodeid2 = shape2.get('nodeId')
    shape_nodes2.append(shape_nodeid2)
for shape3 in root.findall("./Scene/TransformGroup/TransformGroup[@name='birch_stage2']/Shape[@shapeId='3']"):
    shape_nodeid3 = shape3.get('nodeId')
    shape_nodes3.append(shape_nodeid3)

print 'Translations: ', translations
print 'Rotations: ', rotations
print 'Scales: ', scales
print 'NodeIds: ', nodeids
print 'Shape nodeIds: ', shape_nodes1
print 'Shape nodeids2: ', shape_nodes2
print 'Shape NodeIds3: ', shape_nodes3

for new_s3birch in root2.findall("./Scene/TransformGroup/TransformGroup[@name='birch_stage2']"):
    old_translation = new_s3birch.get('translation')
    old_rotation = new_s3birch.get('rotation')
    old_scale = new_s3birch.get('scale')
    old_nodeid = new_s3birch.get('nodeId')
    new_s3birch.set('translation', translations[x])
    if rotations[x] is not None:
        new_s3birch.set('rotation', rotations[x])
    elif rotations[x] is None
        new_s3birch.set('rotation', '')
    if scales[x] is not None:
        new_s3birch.set('scale', scales[x])
    elif scales[x] is None:
        new_s3birch.set('scale', '')
    new_nodeid = new_s3birch.set('nodeId', nodeids[x])
    x += 1
for new_shape in root2.findall("./Scene/TransformGroup/TransformGroup[@name='birch_stage2']/Shape[@shapeId='1']"):
    old_shape = new_shape.get('nodeId')
    new_shape.set('nodeId', shape_nodes1[y])
    y += 1
for new_shape2 in root2.findall("./Scene/TransformGroup/TransformGroup[@name='birch_stage2']/Shape/Shape[@shapeId='2']"):
    old_shape2 = new_shape2.get('nodeId')
    new_shape2.set('nodeId', shape_nodes2[z])
    z += 1
for new_shape3 in root2.findall("./Scene/TransformGroup/TransformGroup[@name='birch_stage2']/Shape[@shapeId='3']"):
    old_shape3 = new_shape3.get('nodeId')
    new_shape3.set('nodeId', shape_nodes3[a])
    a += 1

tree2.write('output.xml')
```